# Showing the div when display is set to none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing around with jQuery and the drag and drop features. I have a `div` which is set to `hidden` in the CSS. When activating the drag element, the `droppable` element should be shown by setting `display` to `inline` (which is the default value).

However, `display: inline;` doesn't overrule `display: none;`. How can this be done (either through jQuery or CSS)?

My current code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Visual feedback</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    #draggable2 { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
    #droppable2 { width: 120px; height: 120px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
    #droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 20px; display: none; }
    .droppable-highlight { display: inline; }
  h3 { clear: left; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable2",
      activeClass: "droppable-highlight",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Feedback on activating draggable:</h3>

<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" >
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Tinker.io link: http://tinker.io/bf197

Comment: This is because the ID selector is more specific (therefore takes higher priority) than the class selector. You will have to set it via the `.css()` method.

Comment: @Terry Could you tell me how this is done? I suppose in the `droppable()` part. I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @Devator: The problem as far as I can tell is that the class isn't being added (I dealt with the specificity problem by -- just for this experiment -- changing the CSS rule's selector to `#droppable.droppable-highlight`). But watching the element in Chrome's dev tools, I don't see the class get added to the droppable, although it seems to me from the docs that what should happen.

Comment: @Devator: Also, a side note: The default `display` value for `div` isn't `inline`, it's `block`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, it doesn't add it. I'm not sure if it's a bug or something but if you try the [jQuery demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#visual-feedback) you don't see it added either (the second example).

Comment: @Devator; Yeah, not an *answer*, but I can tell you why it's not working: The jQuery UI code isn't adding the class when `#droppable` has `display: none`, but it *does* add it if it doesn't. Here's an updated tinker without `display: none`: http://tinker.io/bf197/1 If you watch in dev tools, you'll see the class get added (and the border turns red). But look at this one with `display: none` again: http://tinker.io/bf197/2 If you watch in dev tools, the class never gets added. Apparently jQuery UI ignores the droppable if it's invisible.

Comment: @Devator: *"if you try the jQuery demo you don't see it added either (the second example)"* Yes, I do, and I do in my tinker without `display: none` as well. So I think this is something you might need to raise as a change with the jQuery UI team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the jQuery UI code isn't adding the class to the droppable when the droppable is hidden (has `display: none`). It *does* add it if it *is* visible.

Here's an updated tinker without `display: none`: http://tinker.io/bf197/1

```css
#droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 20px; }
#droppable.droppable-highlight { border-color: red; display: block; }
```

If you watch in Chrome's dev tools or similar, you'll see the class get added (and the border turns red).

But look at this one with `display: none` again: http://tinker.io/bf197/2

```css
#droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 20px; display: none; }
#droppable.droppable-highlight { border-color: red; display: block; }
```

If you watch in dev tools, the class never gets added. Apparently jQuery UI ignores the droppable if it's invisible.

You may need to raise this as an issue with the jQuery UI team, as the code appears to be explicitly checking for this case.

I did find a partial work-around: Using `visibility` rather than `display`: http://tinker.io/bf197/3

```css
#droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 20px; visibility: hidden; }
#droppable.droppable-highlight { visibility: visible; }
```

That works, but of course, has the issue that elements with `visibility: hidden` still consume their layout space.

You can remove the element from the layout without making it `display: none` and get the effect you want: http://tinker.io/bf197/5

```css
#droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 40px; position: absolute; left: -10000px; }
#droppable.droppable-highlight { border-color: red; position: static; }
```

That works by positioning the element off-page in the normal case, but then overriding that positioning when it has the class. Other than hacking the jQuery UI code, I think that's as close to the `display: none` behavior as you're going to get.

---

Other notes:

- I updated the selector on the rules above so it was specific enough, since otherwise the ID selector's specificity outrules the class selector's specificity.
- The default `display` value for `div` is `block`, not `inline`.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Are you aware of **any** workaround to make `display` work instead of `visibility`? Setting a complete different class isn't an issue.

Comment: @Devator: I did come up with one further idea, I've added it to the answer. It should be functionally identical to the `display: none` user experience, even though the element is never actually hidden (just off-page).

Comment: Cheers, works better :-) However there's one (minor) issue that has arrived because of this. Have a look at [this link](http://tinker.io/bf197/6). When you drag the `div`, you'll see the `div` moves down so the position with the mouse is no longer accurate. In my application this is quite an issue. Do you have any clever idea to fix this?

Comment: @Devator: Well, that's a consequence of the fact that we're moving the element back into the static flow. Offhand, I'd say your choices are either to move the draggables *out* of the static flow, or don't move the droppable back into it (e.g., continue to position it absolutely, but when it has the class, change `left` [and `top` if necessary] to move it where you want it).

Comment: Hmm, what I was afraid of. Thanks anyway for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of [CSS preference rules](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

consider this code:

```
#droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 20px; display: none; }
.droppable-highlight { display: inline; }
```

The first one is an id-selector, which is more specific than the second one (a class selector). Changing the `.droppable-highlight` to `#droppable.droppable-highlight` will do the trick :)

You also need to do the same for `#droppable.ui-state-highlight` since the `droppable-highlight` class is removed when you let go.

Secondly, when an element is `display:none`, it takes up no space on the screen and you cannot "drop" onto it. Instead, use `visibility`

So, the final code is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Visual feedback</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    #draggable2 { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
    #droppable2 { width: 120px; height: 120px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
    #droppable { border-width: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: #585FCC; height: 20px; visibility:hidden; }
    #droppable.droppable-highlight { border-color: red; visibility:visible; }
    #droppable.ui-state-highlight { border-color: red; visibility:visible; }
  h3 { clear: left; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable2",
      activeClass: "droppable-highlight",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Feedback on activating draggable:</h3>

<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" >
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

http://tinker.io/bf197/4

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm really looking for `display` rather than `visibility` though (since `visibility` still takes space in the layout).

Comment: @Devator: Use absolute positioning then.